# How to add component in a loop in angular 6

Tags: angular

I have a component with a 2 input fields. When user clicks on add button, it should pop up component as a row every time. In the end all the inputs should be collected in array of objects.

For e.g. 
Component template has

```
model : Search{
input1: String
input2: String
}
```

This should be displayed as a row when user clicks on add button. And in the end result should be collected as `Search[]`

When the page loads, component should be displayed in `ngFor` something like this in theory

```
  <*ngFor="on search components">
         <app-search> </app-search>
 </>
```

Comment: More of a sharing of requirements than a question with an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) don't ya think?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like you'd want something like:

```
<app-search
    [inputOne]="search.input1"
    [inputTwo]="search.input2" 
    *ngFor="let search of searchArray">
</app-search>
```

This is assuming that `searchArray` is a public property on your class with a type of `Search[]`.